# Kill Linux process just ran

Tags: java, process, logging, kill, tail

```
tail -f test.log
```

Above command will tail the log which runs the process behind the scenes. How can I kill that particular process ?

I can press "Ctrl-Z" on the shell but I am running that command using Java and need to kill that process.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you [start a subprocess with Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) you get back [a `Process` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) corresponding to the running process.  You can use [`destroy()` method on the `Process` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29) to kill the running command.

So you'd start it with:

```
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"tail","-f","test.log"});
```

and kill it with:

```
 p.destroy();
```

If you are just reading new lines added to a file, have you considered doing this natively in Java?  Reading the file is pretty straightforward:

```
 try {
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tail.log"));

  while (true) {
    String line;

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
      //You'll probably want to do something other than println()
      System.out.println(line);
    }

    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      break;
    }

  }

  input.close();
 }
 catch (IOException ioe) {
   //Handle this
 }
```

You'll probably want to run this in another `Thread`.  And unlike `tail -f` the above code doesn't handle the file being rewritten from the beginning rather than appended to, but you could fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try for a `killall tail`, but this will kill all running tail processes.

The better way is to use the returned `Process`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Once you have

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tail -f test.log");
```

you can

```
child.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

to find all the java processes, and then just kill the one you want.